# Responsive web design: Android default browser "thinks" that he is larger than he is

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've got following Meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

and CSS rules

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 640px) { ... }
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) { ... }
```

When I open site by Chrome on my phone everything works as expected - `max-device-width: 480px` rules are used. But when I open site by Android 4 default browser it uses `max-device-width: 640px` rules. Can you explain such behaviour?

Comment: Did you try with `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`?

Comment: With `max-width` it works as expected. But we don't want to display mobile design when user changes the size of browser window. So we are using `max-device-width`

Comment: You mean _size of browser window_ on PCs?

Comment: Yes, we use same html/css for all devices. So PC user can change width of browser. When browser window width is pretty small mobile design will be displayed which is bad for our customers

Comment: Can't you assume that 99.9% of PC screens are **at least** 1024px?

Comment: When you use `max-width` screen resolution doesn't matter... anyway it doesn't explains the problem.

Comment: Yes, but why do you assume that users will resize their browsers?

Comment: Well... We are developers.. We are not customers. Personally I would use `max-width`

Comment: I wouldn't care if the user resizes his browser and expects the website to look like desktop. E.g. do you try to predict user's browser plugins and how they can destroy the layout? I bet you don't. It's the same with window resizing. Please, refer to [thebestdesigns.com](http://www.thebestdesigns.com/), review some websites, resize the browser window and you'll see that developers don't care about such things. I'd even say it is **recommended** to make website responsive even on PCs. Right now, you're trying to spoil the layout for users who resize their browsers on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try using this tag `@media(max-width: 640px){...}` and `@media(max-width: 480px){...}`..

Comment: pls check my comment above - we would like to use `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`

Comment: that's all I know about max-device-width

Comment: Looks like Android browser treats `screen resolution` == `device width`